# HOW 2 place text on an <img>-tag?

Tags: css, image, css-position

Im just wondering how to place html-text on a . Shall I use the absolute -position for this matter?

**Just so you know Im gonna use the img in a fluid-grid layout.**

Thanks for yr ideas?

Comment: I can't understand what do you want to do

Comment: @sirLisko thanks any way I found the answer my by self! read my last comment below :)

Answer (score 3):

To place text on an image tag on hover use this...

```
<img src="#" title="YOUR TEXT HERE" alt="" width="" height="" />
```

The title will display when someone hovers over the image. The alt tag is what is shown when the image for some reason or another cannot be displayed. These are both useful attributes to use as some screen readers will use the title tag.

If you want actual text over the image you could do something like...

```
<img src="#" title="YOUR TEXT HERE" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><span style="margin: 20px 0 0 -80px;">YOUR TEXT</span>
```

This will display the text 20 pixels from the top of your image and 20 pixels in considering your image is 100x100px.

Comment: I found the solution myself! but thanks any way for this trick! the solution was  following the idea that I wrote in the beginning about using 2 divs: the one having the <img>-tag and the other with text <p>. Then the last one setting to absolute-position and then float it on top of the other one!